# How to open whatsapp popup when we share text on whatsapp from the app in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, share

I want to show a popup before sharing a text on WhatsApp if the users have two whatsapp.

Like this:

[image]

Here is code:

```
try {
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            i.setType("image/*");
            i.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            String shareMessage = newsModel.getTitle() + "\n\n" + "That's Awesome...\uD83D\uDC40 \n\n Install Now!☺☺ \n\n";
            shareMessage = shareMessage + "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + "\n\n";
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareMessage);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Share News from " + this.getString(R.string.app_name)));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ContentValue", e.getMessage());

            try {
                FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                i.setType("image/*");
                i.setPackage("com.whatsapp.w4b");
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                String shareMessage = newsModel.getTitle() + "\n\n" + "That's Awesome...\uD83D\uDC40 \n\n Install Now!☺☺ \n\n";
                shareMessage = shareMessage + "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + "\n\n";
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareMessage);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Share News from " + this.getString(R.string.app_name)));

            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

This code works properly to share text on WhatsApp but the problem is through this code WhatsApp opens directly and the popup does not show.
I want to show the popup as the given picture below please help me solve this problem.